# Prove that $(A\cup B) - (A \oplus B) = A \cap B$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

I need to show that $(A\cup  B) - (A \oplus B) = A \cap B$

I'm not sure I proved it with a correct way, do you think it's correct?

The 'solution' is in the pictures below.
[image]

[image]

MY SOLUTION AGAIN: [image]

Comment: Use the approach advocated in your other question.

Comment: @Did I did, the question is, did I prove it right with the statements?

Comment: I fail to see you using the systematic approach I underlined in the comment to the other question.

Comment: @Did Uploaded another solution. check it out.

Comment: OK. I promise to comment on it as soon as you stop posting images of sloppy barely drafted squiggles as questions.

Comment: Justify $(x \in \overline{A} \lor x \in B) \cap (x \in \overline{B} \lor x \in A)$ iff $x \in A \land B$. This needs a little work (the distributivity in my algebraic answer is used).

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As to your first proof: why $x \in (A \cup B)\setminus (A - C)$ ($C$ should be $B$, I think) iff $x \in A$?

$x \in A \oplus B$ iff $x$ is exactly in one of $A$ or $B$.
So if $x$ is in the union, so in at least one of $A$ or $B$, but not in just one, it has to be in both. So in $A \cap B$.

And if it is in $A \cap B$, it's certainly in the union, but not in $A \oplus B$, as it is in both $A$ and $B$, not exactly one. So it's in the difference.

Purely algebraic is also possible: $(A \cup B) - (A \oplus B) = (A \cup B) - ((A - B) \cup (B -A)) = (A \cup B) \cap ((A \cap B^c) \cup (B \cap A^c))^c$, applying $C - D = C \cap D^c$ a few times.

Applying de Morgan this equals $A \cup B) \cap (A \cap B^c)^c \cap (B \cap A^c)^c$, then de Morgan twice again to get $(A \cup B) \cap (A^c \cup B) \cap (B^c \cup A)$. Then apply distributivity to get the union of 8 intersections:

$$(A \cap A^c \cap B) \cup (A \cap A^c \cap A) \cup (A \cap B \cap B^c) \cup (A \cap B \cap A) \cup (B \cap A^c \cap B^c) \cup (B \cap A^c \cap A) \cup (B \cap B \cap B^c) \cup (B \cap B \cap A)$$ where all terms cancel (because they contain a set and its complement) except two terms $A \cap B$ which have the union $A \cap B$ of course. This translates directly to a proof using quantifiers as well.

Comment: I need to prove logically, like I tried with the second picture. the question is, did I prove it right, logically with the statements?

Comment: a) my proof is perfectly logical. b) I gave a criticism of your proof already.

Comment: I've just uploaded my solution again, more detailed. what do you think now?

Answer (score 1):

The stipulation $x\in A\cup B$ says $x$ is in at least one of $A$ or $B$. The stipulation $x\in A\oplus B$ says $x$ is in exactly one of $A$ or $B$.  That $x\in (A\cup B)-(A\oplus B)$ says that $x$ lies in both $A$ and $B$; hence $x\in A \cap B$.

This argument reverses easily.

Comment: I need to prove logically, like I tried with the second picture. the question is, did I prove it right, logically with the statements?